# "continue" or "be continued"

Tags: passive-voice

The following are the sentences that I wrote:

> The trend should be continued.
>
> The trend should continue.

Are both grammatically correct? Is there any preference?

Comment: Both are correct.. 
You can't give preference without having the complete context.

Comment: The latter is far more common and idiomatic; the trend should continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The trend should continue

This would be used if you were giving someone a forecast. For example:

> And if you look at the numbers, everyone is seeing reduced sales. This trend should continue until November when Black Friday will make the sales spike.

In this case, you are giving someone and opinion as to what "should" happen. Meaning what you think the most likely scenario will be.

If you were to use

> should be continued

It is more in terms of giving advice or commands. For example:

> The study of cancer should be continued until effective cures are discovered.

In this case, someone is saying that people should continue studying cancer, not that they will, but that they recommend that they do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are both grammatically correct. The preference for which one though depends largely on the context. As we don't have that context, we can't favor one over the other.